# Plot data with week numbers on the x-axis in AMChart5

Tags: amcharts, linechart, amcharts5

I'm a bit lost here while using AMCharts5. There are just too many configuration parameters. So, let's assume the following data series:

```
{
    date: new Date(2021, 0, 5).getTime(),
    value: 156
},
{
    date: new Date(2021, 0, 6).getTime(),
    value: 33
},
```

one sample per day [DEMO](https://codepen.io/scaljeri/pen/KKyzvYN)

My question is about the labels on the X axis. In that demo its shows the days, 01/01, 01/02, etc. But what I would like to have is: week 1, week 2, etc. So we need data grouping (I think). I tried the following

```
// Create X-Axis
let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(
  am5xy.DateAxis.new(root, {
     groupData: true,
     baseInterval: { timeUnit: "week", count: 7 },
     renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {})
  })
);
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/scaljeri/pen/ZEaWXEX)

but considering the outcome, I get the impressing I'm tweaking the wrong parameters here :)

Any help would be appreciated!